# android- listview adapter not returning correct position

Tags: android, listview, arraylist, android-adapter

I have a row file for my listview which has 3 elements. A name on the left side of the row. An Imageview(Right Arrow which indicates going to next page) and a main LinearLayout in which i have placed these items.

Here is my getView() method of my adapter..

@Override

```
 public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        if(convertView==null){     

        convertView=LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.activity_row_mail_category,null);
        holder=new Holder();
        setView(convertView,position);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    }
    else {
        holder= (Holder) convertView.getTag();
        setView(convertView,position);
    }

    holder.Name.setText(mailCategoryArrayList.get(position).getCat_name());

    return convertView;
}
```

Holder is a static class which i have made in the adpater itself.

```
static class Holder{

    TextView Name;
    ImageView next;
    LinearLayout mainLayout;
}
```

Here is the setView method which i called from getView

```
private void setView(final View convertView,final int position) {

    holder.Name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.listview_row_title);
    holder.next = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.next);
    holder.main = (LinearLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.main);

    holder.next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view)

          Log.e("tag","Position:"+position);

        }
    });

    holder.mailCategoryMain.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            holder.next.performClick();

    });
```

Whenever i run the app and click on the layout i get the position as the last index of my arrayList but when i click the imageview i get the correct position. So what is the problem with performClick() function and why does this occur when i am simply telling android to click the image view programatically instead of manually?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Initialze your `holder` inside `setView()` function will solve the problem

```
private void setView(final View convertView,final int position) {

    Holder holder = new holder();
    holder.Name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.listview_row_title);
    holder.next = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.next);
    holder.main = (LinearLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.main);

    holder.next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view)

          Log.e("tag","Position:"+position);

        }
    });

    holder.mailCategoryMain.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            holder.next.performClick();

    });
```

on your code you are  using the same `instance` of `holder` and it saves the last value, hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
Holder holder;
    if(convertView==null){     

    convertView=LayoutInflater.from(context)
    .inflate(R.layout.activity_row_mail_category,null);

    holder=new Holder();
    holder.Name.setText(mailCategoryArrayList.get(position).getCat_name());
    holder.Name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.listview_row_title);
    holder.next = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.next);
    holder.main = (LinearLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.main);
    convertView.setTag(holder);
    }else {
       holder= (Holder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    holder.next.setTag(position);//To avoid finalize
    holder.next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onClick(View view)
       Integer pos=(Integer)view.getTag();
       Log.e("tag","Position:"+pos);

       }
    });

    holder.mailCategoryMain.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onClick(View view) {
           holder.next.performClick();

    });
return convertView;
}
```